# How to determine whether the colour format is RGB or BGR ?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, cgcolor, bgr

Lets assume ,

```
 cgcolor = Any_UIColor.cgColor
```

Now , how can I determine whether **`components`** of **`cgcolor`** is in  **`RGB`** or **`BGR`** sequence ? (Number of components is 4)

Or, **`UIColor`** will always be in **`R G B`** format ?!

Comment: My guess is 4 components is a CMYK color space. If you accept any kind of color space as input, the components could be in any order. In the extremely general case you may even have 3 shades of red as components. Is it possible to convert the color to a known color space first?

Comment: @Mats what if RGB and Alpha makes 4 ?

Comment: I guess RGBA  used for `cgColor`

Comment: @Roy I mistook it for the number of components on the color space. I apologise for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `colorSpace` property of `CGColor`.

> /* Return the color space associated with `color'. */
>
> ```
> @available(iOS 2.0, *)
> public var colorSpace: CGColorSpace? { get }
> ```

**Example:**

```
    let colorspace = UIColor.red.cgColor.colorSpace
```

`CGColorSpaceModel` will give you the exact model of the color that you are using.

```
    let colorspace = UIColor.red.cgColor.colorSpace?.model
```

Refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspacemodel

Comment: Thanks your answer is helpful . But it still can't find the difference between RGB and BGR

Comment: I don’t think BGR is supported by the API.